# Why is this powershell -or filter not working?

Tags: powershell

I have an object saved to a variable with lots of records. I want to filter the object results based on two columns. The same value can appear in either column. The filter works correctly on the `HostName` column. But doesn't correctly filter on the `RecordData` column. There is a result there but the filter isn't retrieving it.

Below is an example of the results missing. All 4 rows should appear in the first query. I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help?

```
PS H:\> $DNSRecord | where { ($_.HostName -like "*gcod049*") -or ($_.RecordData -like "*gcod049*") }

HostName                  RecordType Type       Timestamp            TimeToLive      RecordData                                        
--------                  ---------- ----       ---------            ----------      ----------                                        
gcod049.domainname.com  A          1          0                    00:20:00        10.26.101.49                                      
gcod049                   A          1          0                    00:20:00        10.26.101.49                                      

PS H:\> $DNSRecord | where { ($_.hostname -like "*ssrsdev*") }

HostName                  RecordType Type       Timestamp            TimeToLive      RecordData                                        
--------                  ---------- ----       ---------            ----------      ----------                                        
ssrsdev.domainname.com  CNAME      5          0                    01:00:00        gcod049.domainname.com.                         
ssrsdev                   CNAME      5          0                    01:00:00        gcod049.domainname.com.
```

**UPDATE: When I use Select or Select-Object with .ToString(), the value is completely different.

```
PS H:\> $DNSRecord | 
 Select HostName, RecordData, @{Name="RecordDataString";Expression={$_.RecordData.ToString()}} | 
 where { ($_.HostName -like "*gcod049*") -or ($_.RecordData -like "*gcod049*") }

HostName                 RecordData               RecordDataString        
--------                 ----------               ----------------        
gcod049.domainname.com DnsServerResourceRecordA DnsServerResourceRecordA
gcod049                  DnsServerResourceRecordA DnsServerResourceRecordA

PS H:\> $DNSRecord | 
 Select-Object -Property HostName, RecordData, @{Name="RecordDataString";Expression={$_.RecordData.ToString()}} | 
 where { ($_.HostName -like "*ssrsdev*") -or ($_.RecordData -like "*ssrsdev*") }

HostName                 RecordData                   RecordDataString            
--------                 ----------                   ----------------            
ssrsdev.domainname.com DnsServerResourceRecordCName DnsServerResourceRecordCName
ssrsdev                  DnsServerResourceRecordCName DnsServerResourceRecordCName
```

**Here the object get-member properties...**

```
$DNSRecord | gm


   TypeName: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/Microsoft/Windows/DNS/DnsServerResourceRecord

Name                      MemberType Definition                                                                                                                                         
----                      ---------- ----------                                                                                                                                         
Clone                     Method     System.Object ICloneable.Clone()                                                                                                                   
Dispose                   Method     void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()                                                                                                         
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                     
GetCimSessionComputerName Method     string GetCimSessionComputerName()                                                                                                                 
GetCimSessionInstanceId   Method     guid GetCimSessionInstanceId()                                                                                                                     
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                  
GetObjectData             Method     void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context), void ISerializab...
GetType                   Method     type GetType()                                                                                                                                     
ToString                  Method     string ToString()                                                                                                                                  
DistinguishedName         Property   string DistinguishedName {get;}                                                                                                                    
HostName                  Property   string HostName {get;}                                                                                                                             
PSComputerName            Property   string PSComputerName {get;}                                                                                                                       
RecordClass               Property   string RecordClass {get;}                                                                                                                          
RecordData                Property   CimInstance#Instance RecordData {get;set;}                                                                                                         
RecordType                Property   string RecordType {get;}                                                                                                                           
Timestamp                 Property   CimInstance#DateTime Timestamp {get;}                                                                                                              
TimeToLive                Property   CimInstance#DateTime TimeToLive {get;set;}                                                                                                         
Type                      Property   uint16 Type {get;}
```

Comment: The `-like` operator operates on whatever `$_.RecordData.ToString()` evaluates to, which may not be the same as what the default display output shows.

Comment: RecordData is an object, not a string.

Comment: -like will convert the left side to a string, if it has to.  What does $_.recorddata.tostring() say?

Comment: @js2010 - When I use Select or Select-Object with .ToString(), the value is completely different. Is it possible to pull the correct value displayed as the object.

Comment: Maybe there's some subproperty that has the name.  I don't have that command.

Comment: You can really go overboard and look in the format xml file for that object type and see how they display the hostname, and use the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the table view for type DnsServerResourceRecord's RecordData property, from the file DnsServerPsProvider.Format.ps1xml in the folder C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsServer.  It has a *long* list of if/else statements for this property.  I have the dnsserver module from installing rsat in windows 10, but I don't know how to get get-dnsserverresourcerecord working.

But you can refer to $_.RecordData.HostNameAlias for CNAME types.  Ironically, canonical name means "real name".

```
elseif( $_.RecordType -eq "CNAME")
{
    $_.RecordData.HostNameAlias
}
```

```
$DNSRecord | where { $_.HostName -match 'gcod049' -or
  $_.RecordData.HostNameAlias -match 'gcod049' }
```

Or sometimes it's easier to pipe to findstr /i to look for something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing powershell to evaluate the `-or` first with parenthesis inside the `where { ... }` like this:

```
$DNSRecord | where { (($_.HostName -like "*gcod049*") -or ($_.RecordData -like "*gcod049*")) }
```

Comment: [about Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence) implies that all parentheses in your command are superfluous.